# Добавить число к каждому элементу списка

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream

Не могу добавить к каждому элементу списка число 1. В чем проблема? 
Как  сделать этот же с помощью Stream.api?

```
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(3);
    numbers.add(4);
    numbers.add(5);

    for (Integer integer: numbers){
        integer=integer+1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Тип `Integer` является `immutable`, вы не можете изменить значение полей этого объекта. Каждый раз когда вы каким либо образом меняете объект этого типа, вы на самом деле просто получаете новый объект.

```
a = a + 1;  // что вы пишите
a = Integer.valueOf(a + 1); // что происходит на самом деле
```

В цикле `for (Integer integer: numbers)` вы присваиваете переменной `integer` ссылку на объект, хранящуюся в списке, потом присваиваете этой переменной ссылку на другой объект (условно `integer+1`). У переменной `integer` ссылка поменялась. Естественно, это ни как не повлияло на список.

Чтобы ваш цикл заработал, кладите в ячейки списка новые объекты в явном виде:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
        numbers.set(i, numbers.get(i) + 1); // new Integer (numbers.get(i) + 1)
    }
```

или, если вам так мил Stream API, сделайте целиком новый список

```
    numbers = numbers.stream()
            .map(x -> x +1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```